# Why was the last scene of "Wonder Woman 1984" shown in a different aspect ratio than the rest of the film?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

In the final scene of *WW84*, Diana meets the man whose body Steve possessed. Unlike the rest of the film, this scene is not presented in anamorphic widescreen.

Why is this...?

Comment: Sorry, I may be missing something but what's scope?

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is using 'scope' as the shortened form of [CinemaScope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CinemaScope). That final scene is shot in different dimensions from the scenes immediately preceding it, and (as far as I can tell from a quick check) the rest of the film as well.

Comment: @LogicDictates You guessed it right.

Comment: https://ymcinema.com/2019/12/09/wonder-woman-1984-was-shot-entirely-on-film-another-proof-that-film-is-alive-and-kicking/ This article talks about the cameras that were used during filming, perhaps there is some insight there? At work right now and can't read lengthy articles.

Comment: Cinemascope? What is this, 1959?

Comment: @NKCampbell: it's 1984, pay attention.

Comment: @Randy Root. J - I've reworded your question to more precisely capture the essence of what _I think_ you were asking. Feel perfectly free to roll the edit back if you disagree with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to various articles I've checked, the director, Patty Jenkins, and the cinematographer, Matthew Jensen, wanted to shoot the entire film in IMAX format with a 1.90:1 aspect ratio.

However, that proved impractical for both financial and logistical reasons, so it was decided to shoot only the opening and closing scenes with 65 mm IMAX cameras, while the rest of the film was shot with a variety of more conventional 35 mm cameras, leading to a shift in aspect ratios in-between those 'bookend' scenes.

I checked the opening scene in Themyscira, and that is in the 1.90:1 aspect ratio as well.

> **Jensen and Jenkins wanted to shoot the entire project on 65-mm 5-perf for added clarity and resolution; but when that proved to have financial and logistical barriers, they decided to pick specific sequences to shoot in large format.** Once IMAX was confirmed for the opening and closing sequences, 65-mm 5-perf was used to augment the dialogue portion of those IMAX sequences. And the two formats blended easily in the DI.
>
> **The bulk of WW84 was shot on Kodak Vision3 50D 5203, 250D 5207, and 500T 5219, creating a distinct jump in resolution between the IMAX 1.90:1 aspect ratio and the 2.39:1 of anamorphic 35 mm,** and necessitating a 4K finish to ease those transitions.
>
> <sub><sup>[She’s Back…](https://www.icgmagazine.com/web/shes-back/)</sup></sub>